# Why Wrapped Optional Values in Swift? Is it possible to set a variable as optional without declaring a type?

Tags: swift

If I want to make a variable an optional, I can do:

```
var exampleString: String? = nil
```

or

```
var exampleString: String? = "This is a string"
```

**Is it possible to declare an optional value without assigning a type like String, Int, Bool, etc?**

Something like (that doesn't return an error):

```
var exampleVar? = nil
```

I have no use case for why I want to do this, but I'm trying to better understand optionals. I just read through the Optionals section in Swift docs. **If this can be done, would there be any advantage to doing this?**

**Also, why would I not want to use implicitly unwrapped optionals everywhere? What would be the disadvantages of this?** Apple's Swift docs mentions that you shouldn't do this if you intend to reassign a variable to nil. Why?

Thanks so much for your help guys!

Comment: Implicitly unwrapped optionals are dangerous if they might be used when they are nil. The result will be a runtime error aka crash. If the logic of your code guarantees they will be valid whenever they're used then they may be safe. IBOutlets are valid when they're used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to declare an optional value without assigning a type like String, Int, Bool, etc?

No. The reason is that `Optional` (without its generic parameter) is not a complete type — think of it as a *type constructor*, i.e. a way to produce a full type if you give it the missing information.

The compiler needs to know the full type — `Optional<Int>` or `Optional<String>` and so on — to allocate the right amount of memory etc. An `Optional<String>` will take up more memory than an `Optional<Bool>`, even if both are `nil`.

The same is true for other generic types like `Array`. `Array` is the type constructor, `Array<Int>` the complete type.

*Edit: [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) makes a good point: `var exampleVar: Any? = nil` allows you to store any value in this optional. Note that we're still dealing with a full type here — `Optional<Any>`. It's just that all types are compatible with `Any`. In that sense, `Optional<Any>` is not much different from `Optional<SomeProtocol>`, which can store any value that conforms to the `SomeProtocol` protocol.*

Comment: `var exampleVar: Any? = nil`. You now have an optional that can be given any value. I don't recommend this at all but that sort of meets the requirement of the question.

Comment: rmaddy Why would you not suggest using "Any" as a type? What are the disadvantages?

Comment: @EnricoMatassa FYI - put the `@` symbol before the username so the person gets notified. Depending on what you are doing, there may be much better solutions. I'll leave it at that since comments are not the place for such a discussion.

Comment: @rmaddy: That's a good point, thanks. I added a paragraph to my answer.